# how to get the nearest '<' from cursor position in textarea either js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Know these but want something like

```
<script>
    let value = document.getElementById("textarea");
    value.indexOf("<")
    value.lastIndexOf("<")
    value.nearestIndexOf("<") // how can i do it?
</script>
```

Comment: There's nothing like that available in the DOM, take a look at [HTMLTextAreaElement properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement#properties), you can get the cursor position from `selectionStart` property, then you can calculate the distance to the nearest `<` character.

Comment: [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf#parameters) takes a second parameter, fromIndex, so something like `textArea.value.indexOf(char, textArea.selectionStart)`?

Comment: don't worked in practical software @pilchard :( :(

Comment: Maybe you should show us a practical example instead of the hypothetic code?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify what should be selected when the distances are equal to the both directions, here's a snippet, which selects the nearest index from the left-side of the caret.

```js
const textArea = document.querySelector('textarea');

function nearestOf(char, textArea) {
  const text = textArea.value,
    origo = textArea.selectionStart,
    leftIndex = text.lastIndexOf(char, origo - 1),
    rightIndex = text.indexOf(char, origo);
  let distLeft, distRight, indices = {
    [distLeft = leftIndex < 0 ? Infinity : origo - leftIndex]: leftIndex,
    [distRight = rightIndex < 0 ? Infinity : rightIndex - origo + 2]: rightIndex
  };
  return indices[Math.min(distRight, distLeft)];
}

textArea.addEventListener('input', e => {
  const s = nearestOf('<', e.target);
  console.log('nearestOf:', s);
});
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

The code save the nearest `<` characters from the left-side and right-side of the caret to the `Index` variables, the distances are stored in `dist` variables, and in the keys of `indices` object. If the character is not found from the left-side, the corresponding key is set to `Infinity` and the value to -1. The same check is done for the right-side character. If there's no the searched character, `indices` object contains only a single `Infinity` key. The return statement picks the index of the shortest value from the `indices` object by the keys which are representing the distances.

The odd looking constant 2 in `distRight` makes sure, that the left-side is selected when the distances are the same.